Solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{e^{x^2}}dx$ by extracting Gaussian Integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{e^{x^2}}$$
I began by applying some basic trig properties to hopefully leave me with a more approachable integral.
$$\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sin x\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})+\cos x\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$$
$$\implies\sin^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac12(\sin^2x+\cos^2x+2\sin x\cos x)=\frac 12(1+\sin(2x))$$
Here I realized if I expressed the denominator as a negative exponent, I could extract the Gaussian Integral after distributing.
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+\sin(2x))\cdot(e^{-x^2})dx$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx+ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(2x)e^{-x^2}dx$$
$\sin(2x)e^{-x^2}$ appears to be an odd function so the integral on the right is just $0$. This leaves us with the well-known Gaussian Integral and we immediately come to our solution:
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}$$
This problem was provided to me as an extra credit question. Was there a better way of solving this integral? I am familiar with the Gaussian Integral but have never even considered using it while solving an integral so I am unsure of the steps I took. Is there some sort of substitution I could have used or is the $e^{-x^2}$ unavoidable?
I ask this because the prerequisite for this course is only Calc III, which would make this unsolvable for (most likely) everyone in the class. I only recognized the Gaussian integral because I watch a lot of math videos on youtube.

You can solve the Gaussian integral using Calc 1 tools

Yes I think you can do the following$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\sin^2(x+\pi/4)dx\iff I^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}\big(\sin(x+\pi/4)\sin(y+\pi/4)\big)^2dxdy
$$which by the trig identity you pointed out implies$$
I^2=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}\big(1+\sin(2x)+\sin(2y)+\sin(2x)\sin(2y)\big)dxdy.
$$Your observations about odd integrals will also hold and then give$$
I^2=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy
$$which can be done with Calc III tools as you wish (polar).

Using double angle formula, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{e^{x^2}} d x = & \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos \left(2 x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{e^{x^2}} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} d x+ \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2 x)}{e^{x^2}} d x}_{=0 \textrm{ as the integrand is odd}} \\=&\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

Since
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}4\right)e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}4\right)e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx $$
you have:
$$I=\frac12\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}4\right)e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}4\right)e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx\right)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2 $$
